# socket send() repeatable

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having a question regarding send() on TCP sockets.

Is there a difference between:

```
char *text="Hello world";
char buffer[150];

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    send(fd_client, text, strlen(text) );
```

and

```
char *text="Hello world";
char buffer[150];

buffer[0]='\0';
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    strcat(buffer, text);

send(fd_client, buffer, strlen(buffer) );
```

Is there a difference for the receiver side using recv?
Are both going to be one TCP packet?

Even if TCP_NODELAY is set?

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to know. Depends on the implementation of TCP. If it were a UDP socket, they would definitely have different results, where you would have several packets in the first case and one in the second.

TCP is free to split up packets as it sees fit; it emulates a stream and abstracts it's packet mechanics away from the user. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is stream based protocol. If you run Send, it will put some data into OS TCP layer buffer and OS will send it periodically. But if you call Send too quick it might put few arrays into OS TCP layer before the previous one were sent. So it is like stack, it sends whatever it has and put everything in one big array.
Sending is btw done with segmentation by OS TCP layer, and there is as well Nagle's algorithm that will prevent sending small amount data before OS buffer will be big enough to satisfy one segment size.

So yes, there is difference.

TCP is stream based protocol, you can't rely on that single send will be single receive with same amount of data.
Data might merge together and you have to remember about that all the time.

Btw, based on your examples, in first case client will receive all bytes together or nothing. In meantime if sending one big segment will drop somewhere on the way then server OS will automatically resend it. Drop chance for bigger packets is higher so and resending of big segments will lead to some traffic lose. But this is based on percentage of dropped packets and might be not actual for your case at all.

In second example you might receive everything together or parts each separate or some merged. You never know and should implement you network reading that way, that you know how many bytes you expecting to receive and read just that amount of bytes. That way even if there is left some unread bytes they will be read on next "Read".